# JQuery Mobile: list with dynamic search filter

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I start to use JQuery Mobile 1.2.0.I met problem of `listviewwhen I followed the guide to get started.I used the sample code in my html, but the list view had a little problem, like:`

As you can see, the search field clips with the list view.
However it runs well in JQuery website. So I'm a little lost and have no idea what is missing.

Could anyone help me?

Edited:
Source code

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
<li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: can you show the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/fmJhF/) a working example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="some-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Warning</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">    
        <ul data-role="listview" id="thumbs" data-filter="true">
            <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still has the same problem, and I guess it caused by using JQuery Mobile 1.2.0. Finally, I use the second div, and it works. thanks.